# Magento 2: How to get product collection by category?

Tags: magento2, product, category, collection

We are trying to get product collection by category id.

**Block:**

```
protected $_categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{   
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getCategory($categoryId) 
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $category->load($categoryId);
    return $category;
}

public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
{
    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $products;
}
```

and in html:

```
$categoryId = 6; // fetching products in category id 6
$categoryProducts = $block->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

it works fine only if `$categoryId` = the highest level in the category tree. But if I change `$categoryId` to 2 (or 3... or etc but not last in category tree) it doesn't work.

How can I get it work?

Comment: $categoryId =  2 means it is root category. so it will not work for it.

Comment: or 3... or etc but not last in category tree. it's not working.

Comment: are the products directly assigned to the categories? I'm asking because categories have the is_anchor switch which shows all products of all child categories on the category page, but I'm pretty sure those products are not assigned directly to the category. So lodaing the products of a category with the is anchor switch active will still only load the products which are directly assigned to the category while the category page will still render all products of all child categories

Answer (score 8):

I did this task in this way:
In block:

```
protected $_objectManager = null;
protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_category;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    $category = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    return $category;
}

/**
 * Get category object
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
 */
public function getCategory($categoryId)
{
    $this->_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $this->_category->load($categoryId);
    return $this->_category;
}

/**
 * Get all children categories IDs
 *
 * @param boolean $asArray return result as array instead of comma-separated list of IDs
 * @return array|string
 */
public function getAllChildren($asArray = false, $categoryId = false)
{
    if ($this->_category) {
        return $this->_category->getAllChildren($asArray);
    } else {
        return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getAllChildren($asArray);
    }
}

public function getProductCollection($category_id_array)
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category_id_array]);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->setPageSize(9); // fetching only 9 products
    return $collection;
}
```

In phtml:

```
<?php
    $category_id_array = $this->getAllChildren(true,$this->getCurrentCategory()->getEntity_id());
    foreach ($block->getProductCollection($category_id_array) as $product) {
        var_dump($product->getData());
    }
?>
```

and it works in any category.

Comment: I don't know why it worked but only this worked for me after spending 2 days to see the list of the products on the category page.? any particular idea why the products are not displayed on the category page?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following code to resolve your query:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$cateinstance = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$cateid = '14';
$allcategoryproduct = $cateinstance->create()->load($cateid)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: You should never use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()