# How do I get all products in a category?

Tags: collection, catalog

Consider my 'shorts' category below. It has 149 products in. 13 are configurable, the rest are simple products that have a visibility of 'Not visible individually'.

[image: Category listing in admin]

I have the following:

```
$category = $this->categoryRepositoryFactory->create();
$category = $category->get(20);

$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', [1,2,3,4]);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
$collection->setOrder('cat_index_position','DESC');
```

This only retrieves the 13 records with the Configurable products with visibility of 'Catalog, Search'.

(It also doesn't order by position, but that's another matter)

**I want to get a list of ALL of the products in the category - Not visible included.**

I have tried reindexing, cache etc, but no luck.

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96177/magento-2-get-product-collection-using-category-id 2) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/magento-2-how-to-get-product-collection-by-category

Comment: Thanks but that seems to get products in child categories. All my products are assigned to the correct category and I do not wish to retrieve products from other categories. Just ALL the products from the shorts category.

Comment: this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96183/85907 >> get all category but view only main category

Comment: Awesome. Thanks man.

Comment: solve your issues ???If No, let me know other query